# strange behaviour of gdb on next command

Tags: c++, gdb

I am new at gdb and have a cpp file with the following code

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
struct A{
    int a;
    A(int aa) {a = aa;}
};

int main () {
    A aa(2);
    aa.a = 1;
    std::set<int> set_int;
    set_int.insert(1);
    std::vector<int> vec_int;
    vec_int.push_back(1);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled it `g++ -g main.cpp -o main`

then i ran gdb `gdb main`

using commands `b main`, `r`,`n` ...

I got following output

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400aaf: file main.cpp, line 9.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/srb/Desktop/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:9
9   int main () {
(gdb) n
10      A aa(2);
(gdb) 
11      aa.a = 1;
(gdb) 
12      std::set<int> set_int;
(gdb) 
13      set_int.insert(1);
(gdb) 
14      std::vector<int> vec_int;
(gdb) 
15      vec_int.push_back(1);
(gdb) 
16      return 0;
(gdb) 
14      std::vector<int> vec_int;
(gdb) 
12      std::set<int> set_int;
(gdb) 
17  }
(gdb) 
__libc_start_main (main=0x400aa6 <main()>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdbf8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdbe8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:325
325 ../csu/libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) q
```

for me gdb was working fine till `return 0` which is on `line no 16`. after that control moved to `line 14` and then `line 12`.

why was this happening that on pressing n after `line 16` it moved to `line 14` and then `line 12`. According to the first comment `it is due to destruction of set_int and vec_int`. But then why is it not working for `aa`. why is its destructor not called ?

Please explain where I am missing the things. suggest me some place where I can get proper knoweledge to connect the dots.

Comment: "_AFAK it should have exited after `line 9`._" What about destructor calls of `vec_int`, and `set_int`? Shouldn't those be invoked, in your opinion?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius what about destructor of `aa` why is it not called?

Comment: @srbcheema1 `A` has a trivial destructor, hence it is a no-op, and may be optimized away.